# TableView inside TableView cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want create something simular with Tik-Tok comments. Each cell of comment can contains sub-comments.
For this i want to use TableView inside TableViewCell. But i dont know why, my TableView inside TableView cell doesnt want to show, it seems the problem related to row height, but it not clear for me how solve it

MainView

```
final class CommentsView: BaseView {
    
    lazy var tableView = with(UITableView()) {
        $0.separatorStyle = .none
        $0.backgroundColor = .white
        $0.dataSource = self
        $0.delegate = self
        $0.register(item: CommentCell.self)
        $0.estimatedRowHeight = 50.0
        $0.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
    private let sendMsgPanel = with(SendMessagePanelView()) {
        $0.backgroundColor = .white
    }
    
    
    override func setupUI() {
        super.setupUI()
        
        addSubviews([
            tableView,
            sendMsgPanel
        ])
    }
    
    override func setupConstraints() {
        super.setupConstraints()
        tableView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.leading.equalToSuperview().offset(10)
            make.trailing.equalToSuperview()
            make.top.equalToSuperview().offset(20)
            make.bottom.equalTo(sendMsgPanel.snp.top)
        }
        sendMsgPanel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.bottom.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview()
            make.height.equalTo(100)
        }
    }
    
    override func setupVisuals() {
        super.setupVisuals()
    }
}

extension CommentsView: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: CommentCell = tableView.deque(for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    }
}
```

MainCell:

```
final class CommentCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    private let userImageView = with(UIImageView()) {
        $0.image = UIImage(cgImage: Asset.placeholder.image.cgImage!)
        $0.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    }
    private let contentStackView = with(UIStackView.vertical) {
        $0.spacing = 5
    }
    private let nameLnameLabel = with(UILabel.proximaFont(ofSize: .small, weight: .regular)) {
        $0.text = "N L"
        $0.textColor = .gray
    }
    private let commentLabel = with(UILabel.proximaFont(ofSize: .regularSmall, weight: .regular)) {
        $0.text = "Comment"
        $0.textColor = .almostBlack
    }
    
    private let imageSize: CGFloat = 40
    
    private lazy var tableView = with(UITableView()) {
        $0.separatorStyle = .none
        $0.backgroundColor = .white
        $0.dataSource = self
        $0.delegate = self
        $0.register(item: SubCommentCell.self)
        $0.estimatedRowHeight = 50.0
        $0.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    private func commonInit() {
        setupUI()
        setupConstrains()
        setupVisual()
    }
    
    private func setupUI() {
        contentView.addSubviews([
            //userImageView,
            contentStackView,
            tableView
        ])
        contentStackView.addArrangedSubviews([
            nameLnameLabel,
            commentLabel,
        ])
    }
    
    private func setupConstrains() {
        contentStackView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.leading.top.trailing.equalToSuperview()
        }
        tableView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(contentStackView.snp.bottom)
            make.leading.trailing.bottom.equalToSuperview()
        }
    }
    
    private func setupVisual() {
        selectionStyle = .none
        backgroundColor = .white
        userImageView.setRounded(cornerRadius: imageSize / 2)
    }
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
}

extension CommentCell: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: SubCommentCell = tableView.deque(for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    }
}


final class SubCommentCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    private let label = with(UILabel()) {
        $0.text = "sub comment"
    }
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    private func commonInit() {
        setupUI()
        setupConstrains()
        setupVisual()
    }
    
    private func setupUI() {
        contentView.addSubview(label)
    }
    
    private func setupConstrains() {
        label.positionToTheEdges()
    }
    
    private func setupVisual() {
    }
    
}
```

i have no any errors related to constrains

Comment: please share screenshot of current code and desire result screenshot too.

Comment: Why not using sections ?

Comment: Where do you reload the cell table view ?

Comment: @PtitXav thanks for advice, can i use custom view for a section?(with dynamic height for header section)

Comment: @PtitXav where is better to reload the cell table view?

Comment: Just in case you have time to made some code refactors - take a look at collection view's diffable data source and composition layout, and you will never use tableview inside tableview cell again

Comment: @PeteStreem thanks i will change the code with sections(like Ptit Xav sad)

Comment: You can use custom vie for section header [see](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614901-tableview)